# excel drop down that populates table

Tags: excel, populate

I want to create a drop down list on excel that will automatically populate a table once I click on a certain option. For example, if my drop down list has Apples, Oranges, Pears, and Grapes, and I select Apples, I want a table with data about the apple to be populated automatically. I've created the drop downs but I'm unsure how to connect a table with data back to the specific drop down option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your table, you can use IF/Then statements that point to that drop down cell.  If your drop down, for example, is in A1, you can do this where you want your data to show:  `=If($A$1="Apples",[whatever you need to show Apples' info],If($A$1="Oranges",[whatever for Oranges],If($A$1="Pears",[pear stuff],if($A$1="Grapes",[grape info],)))))`

Note: You can do just about any formula, so you could do a vlookup or index/match, just pointing the formulas to your drop down cell.

Edit: I don't know what your info looks like, but for example, you can use index/match to return different types of Apples:

[image]

So, if you change "Apple", in B2, to "Oranges" then the three types will automatically change to "Regular","Xtra-Orange","Clementine".  Is that the sort of thing you're looking to do?

Comment: So I would write these if/then statements in the dropdown cell but how do I link the tables associated with those values?

Comment: No - you would write those statements where your table is.  Can you post some sample data/table, and I can make it more specific/understandable.

Comment: Edited my OP, is that more of what you're looking for?

Comment: If that helps, would you kindly mark as the Answer (click that check mark to make it green) and/or upvote?  Glad to help!